# jquery datatable is not filtering rows from ssp formatted fields. e.g

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, ssp

```
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'name', 'dt' => 1 ),
array( 
    'db'        => 'id',
    'dt'        => 2,
    'formatter' => function( $id, $row ) {
        if($id % 2 == 0){
            return "Even";  
        } 
        else{ 
            return "Odd"; 
        } 
    }
 ),
array( 'db' => 'office',  'dt' => 3 )
```

i can filter rows from id and name fields but not from odd and even field.

Comment: What is "ssp"? (The tag does not provide a definition.)

Comment: Regardless of what "ssp" means, this question appears to be missing information needed for anyone to help you. Please consider providing a [mre].